# How to take input with white space in c++ inside a loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get input with spaces in my code and I figured out using get line() so when I'm trying to use it inside loop but when It enters the loop it throws an exception **terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
Aborted**

So how to fix it?

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N, Q;
    map<pair<string, string>,string> DATA;
    cin>>N;
    while(N--){
    string Code;
    getline(cin,Code);
    for(int i=0;i<Code.length();i++){
        if(Code[i]==' '){
            Code.erase(Code.begin()+i);
        }
    }
    string Tag,Data,Type;
    Tag=Code.substr(1,4);
    int Start=Code.find('"');
    for(int i=Start+1;i<Code.length();i++){
        Data.push_back(Code[i]);
        if(Code[i]=='>'){
            Data.pop_back();
            Data.pop_back();
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=5;i<Code.length();i++){
        Type.push_back(Code[i]);
        if(Code[i]=='='){
            Type.pop_back();
            break;
        }
    }
    DATA.emplace(make_pair(Type,Tag),Data);
    }
    string Print;
    cin>>Print;
    string tag_n,type_n;
    tag_n=Print.substr(0,4);
    type_n=Print.substr(5,Print.length());
    pair<string,string>Val={type_n,tag_n};
    if(DATA.find(Val)!=DATA.end()){
        cout<<DATA[Val];
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not Found!";
    }
}
```

PS:

Thanks for reading

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Where does the exception occurr (which loop)?

Comment: Can you give some sample input that causes the exception?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes in the first while loop (N--)

Comment: I see you are attempting to remove spaces from the string after reading it.  Does your code following this step have an assumption that the string has no spaces?  Because that bit where you remove spaces doesn't work for consecutive spaces.

Comment: @john <tag1 name = "Agent_A">

Comment: @john actually I tried to debug it as soon as it e tera the loop it exits

Comment: Yea @paddy Actually the reason behind removing the space is that as you can see I have made 3 sub string from the string and I know that the input would be similar actually I'm trying to solve a question from hacker rank the input would be <tagx name = "name"> x=TagNo name could be anything

Comment: There are a few problems with the code. But the main one is that you first call to getline is reading the trailing newline after the number of test cases, not reading a fresh line. Add the following after `cin>>N;` add `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` see duplicate for full details.

Comment: Your code is full of assumptions, such as the input succeeds, there are no consecutive whitespace characters, `find('"')` will succeed, and that `Data` contains at least two items when you encounter `'>'`.  On that last point, the standard says that behavior is undefined if you call `pop_back()` on an empty string.  On previous points, if `find()` returns `std::string::npos` then the character was not found.  You should not then go and add 1 to that value and start using it.

Comment: Since you've tagged a whole bunch of modern C++ standards, then why aren't you just using `std::regex`?  It would be perfect for this, without all the horrendous stuff you have right now.

Comment: This is the duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction. Can't vote for it right now

Comment: When `Code` is empty `Tag=Code.substr(1,4)` will throw that exception